# Pass component as a property and respect its named slots in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want my container component to render contents based on child's slot names. Here's an example markup:

```html
<div id="app">
    <Container>
        <component :is="childComponent"></component>
    </Container>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
import Container from './Container'
import someComponent from './someComponent'
export default {
    components: {
         Container,
         someComponent
    },
    data() {
        childComponent: 'someComponent'
    }
}
</script>
```

---

```html
// Container.vue
<template>
    <div>
         <header>
             <slot name="head"></slot>
         </header>
         <div class="ContainerBody">
             <slot name="body"></slot>
         </div>
         <footer>
             <slot name="footer"></slot>
         </footer>
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```html
// Some child component
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 slot="head">Child Title</h1>
        <div slot="body" class="body"><div>Child Body</div></div>
        <footer slot="footer">Child Footer</footer>
    </div>
</template>
```

How do I make it that Vue respects slot names and renders child contents in accordingly named slots, so the result would look like this:

```html
<div>
     <header>
         Child Title
     </header>
     <div class="ContainerBody">
         <div>Child Body</div>
     </div>
     <footer>
         Child Footer
     </footer>
</div>
```

Right now it will only render my child component in an unnamed slot:

```html
<slot></slot>
```

The idea is to render child component differently when it's loaded as a child of Container. I would like it to work with .Vue files and allow child components to still behave as usual when they're not a child of a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want because each component has to have a single root element, which precludes it being plugged in as three separate slots.

What I was able to do was to turn the problem inside-out, making the top-level component the `childComponent` and having it take a `container` prop which it uses to set the `:is` of its root element.

```js
// "importing" async component definitions
const vueContainerComponent = () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve({
  template: '#container-template'
}));

const vueChildComponent = () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve({
  template: '#child-template',
  props: ['container']
}));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    someComponent:() => vueChildComponent().then((spec) => ({
      extends: spec,
      components: {
        Container: vueContainerComponent
      }
    }))
  },
  data: {
    container: 'Container',
    childComponent: 'someComponent'
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

footer {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component :is="childComponent" :container="container"></component>
</div>

<template id="container-template">
  <div>
    <header>
      <slot name="head"></slot>
    </header>
    <div class="ContainerBody">
      <slot name="body"></slot>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <slot name="footer"></slot>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="child-template">
  <div :is="container">
    <h1 slot="head">Child Title</h1>
    <div slot="body" class="body"><div>Child Body</div></div>
    <footer slot="footer">Child Footer</footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see 2 serious limitations for me here, which are: childComponent is not really usable outside of the container unless you're ok with code duplication, it does not work with .Vue components (or I am doing something wrong here since it only replaces my child's `div` with `container`). I would really like my components to work both ways: within a container and without it. And also to use only .Vue files. I'll update my question with these requirements.

Comment: Quick update: in order to use it in Vue components you'll have to include your container in every single component that you want to be able to use within that container. It's only a matter of code duplication now.

Comment: So `.vue` components can't see components declared using `Vue.component`? That's unfortunate.

Comment: @CyberAP See my updated answer. You can use `extends` to introduce the component to its potential containers in the instance that will be using them together.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but can't get it working, probably due to having async components in my code. I am always getting this: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". EDIT: Yeah, that's it. As soon as I make them async it does not work.

Comment: Updated to deal with async components. To do local registration of async components, you have to give it a function returning a Promise, the extension will have to be async if its base component is async.

Comment: Thank you, no luck unfortunately: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. I am using webpack imports: const Container = () => import('./Container');

Comment: Thanks for your help a lot! I solved my issue by adding `.default` to my component in `extends` field.